# Draw diagram in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

[image]

Is there anyone who would like to help me draw this diagram in LaTeX? :-)
I got help yesterday to draw the diagram, point and so on but I can't figure out how to draw the little boxes and the lines between points.

The code I got yesterday, and tried to edit...

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}   
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}    
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,font=\scriptsize,scale=1.8]

 % draw axis

 \draw[->](0,0)--(4,0)node[below]{1};
 \draw[->](0,0)--(0,4)node[left]{1};;

 % draw ticks 

 \foreach \i in {1,2,3}
 {\draw (\i,0.1)--(\i,-0.1)node[below]{$\frac{\i}{4}$};
 \draw (0.1,\i)--(-0.1,\i)node[left]{$\frac{\i}{4}$};
 }

 % draw bullets 

 \foreach \i in {0,...,3}
 {\foreach \j in {0,...,3}
 \node[fill=black,circle,inner sep=1pt] (\i-\j) at (\i,\j) {};
 }

 % label for bullets x and y

 \node[below right] at (2-1){$y_{j}$};
 \node[below] at (1-2){$x_{j}$}; 
 \draw(1-2)--(2,2);
 \draw(1-2)--(1,3);
 \draw[dashed](2-2)--(2,3);
 \draw[dashed](1-3)--(2,3);
 \draw(2-1)--(3,1);
 \draw(2-1)--(2,2);
 \draw[dashed](3-1)--(3,2);
 \draw[dashed](2-2)--(3,2);
 %\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=3pt}](1-2)--(3-2)node[midway,above=4pt] {$|x-y|_\infty$};

 % dashed arrows

 \draw[dashed,<->](0.2,0)--(0.2,1);
 \draw[dashed,<->](0,0.2)--(1,0.2)node[midway,above,font=\tiny]{$2^{-m}=\frac{1}{2}$};

\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do this for me question are really poor. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: try in pstricks

Comment: Most of that diagram was drawn for you in a different question, you could at the very least refer to that and specify what the trouble is here. Saying "I have this code which does the following, how can I extend it to do this other thing" is much better than just posting an image of what you need done.

Comment: I got help to draw the akses, points and so on. What i can't figure out is how to draw the little boxes and the dashed lines between points

Comment: Sorry, i'm new to this. I understand i should refer, i will do that next time.

Comment: I found out, how to draw the outer box, it's the lines between points, i can't do.

Comment: You should add the code as a MWE of what you got already and revise your description and question...

Comment: @Jeanett - You can still edit your question. You can refer to your other question and you can include the code you have now. In this way, we can help you better.

Comment: I tried do add the code but i don't think i did it right because it doesn't show :/

Answer (score 4):

To draw cross hatch box you can use `\clip` or `\path[clip]` inside a `scope` environment to limit showing diagonal lines inside a path which follows the edge of the two boxes.

```
\clip(1,3)--(2,3)--(2,2)--(3,2)--(3,1)--(2,1)--(2,2)--(1,2)--cycle;
```

---

**Code**

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}   
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}    
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,font=\scriptsize,scale=1.3]

 % draw axis

 \draw[->](0,0)--(6,0);
 \draw[->](0,0)--(0,6);

 % draw ticks 

 \draw (5,2pt)--(5,-2pt)node[below]{$1$};
 \draw (2pt,5)--(-2pt,5)node[left]{$1$};


 % draw bullets 

 \foreach \i in {0,...,4}
 {\foreach \j in {0,...,4}
 \node[fill=black,circle,inner sep=1pt]  at (\i,\j) {};
 }

 % label for bullets x and y

 \node[below] at (2,1){$y_{j}$};
 \node[below] at (1,2){$x_{j}$}; 
 \draw(1,2)--(2,2);
 \draw(1,2)--(1,3);
 \draw[dashed](2,2)--(2,3);
 \draw[dashed](1,3)--(2,3);
 \draw(2,1)--(3,1);
 \draw(2,1)--(2,2);
 \draw[dashed](3,1)--(3,2);
 \draw[dashed](2,2)--(3,2);

 % cross hatch boxes

 \begin{scope}
 \clip(1,3)--(2,3)--(2,2)--(3,2)--(3,1)--(2,1)--(2,2)--(1,2)--cycle;
 \foreach \sh in {-4,-3.9,...,4}
 {\draw[help lines] (1,1+\sh)--(3,3+\sh);}
 \end{scope}
 \draw[dashed](1.5,3)--(1.5,2)node[below,xshift=6pt]{$x_{j+1}$};
 \draw[dashed](1,2.5)--(2,2.5);
 \draw[dashed](2.5,2)--(2.5,1)node[below,xshift=6pt]{$y_{j+1}$};
 \draw[dashed](2,1.5)--(3,1.5);

 \node [fill=black,circle,inner sep=1pt,label=below:$x$ ]at(1.8,2.3){};
 \node [fill=black,circle,inner sep=1pt,label=below:$y$ ]at(2.2,1.8){};

 % dashed arrows

 \draw[dashed,<->](0.3,0)--(0.3,1);
 \draw[dashed,<->](0,0.3)--(1,0.3)node[pos=0.6,above,font=\tiny]{$2^{-j}$};

\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-0.335,-0.415)(5.5,5.5) % frame parameters found manually
  \psline{->}(0,0)(5.5,0)
  \psline{->}(0,0)(0,5.5)
  \multido{\iA = 0+1}{5}{\multido{\iB = 0+1}{5}{\psdot(\iA,\iB)}}
  \psline(5,-0.1)(5,0.1)
  \uput[270](5,0){$1$}
  \psline(-0.1,5)(0.1,5)
  \uput[180](0,5){$1$}
 {\psset{linestyle = none, fillstyle = hlines}
  \psframe(1,2)(2,3)
  \psframe(2,1)(3,2)}
  \psline(1,3)(1,2)(2,2)(2,1)(3,1)
 {\psset{linestyle = dashed}
  \psline(1,3)(2,3)(2,2)(3,2)(3,1)
  \psline(1,2.5)(2,2.5)
  \psline(1.5,3)(1.5,2)
  \psline(2,1.5)(3,1.5)
  \psline(2.5,2)(2.5,1)
  \psline{<->}(0.4,0)(0.4,1)
  \psline{<->}(0,0.4)(1,0.4)}
 {\tiny
  \uput[45](0.4,0.4){$2^{-j}$}
  \uput[270](1,2){$x_{j}$}
  \uput[295](1.5,2){$x_{j + 1}$}
  \uput[270](2,1){$y_{j}$}
  \uput[295](2.5,1){$y_{j + 1}$}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]